# Select multiple columns of data for a UsedRange Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Hope someone can help.
I am trying to select data from 4 columns to be part of one `UsedRange`.

I do not wish to select the entire column, just the data in each of the four columns (C,E,F,H) as one range. If there were no gaps in the sheet I could easily use `Range(C1:H5) etc.

Each column has different number of rows which regularly change.

[image: Example]

Comment: But row 5 is also part of the `UsedRange`. Please clarify.

Comment: Sorry yes my bad, edited now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### A dynamic solution using a loop and [union()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union)

This selects the exact used range of each column. Disadvantage is that this selection doesn't allow copy/paste (see alternative solution).

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SelectUsedRangeOfSeveralColumns()     
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim ArrCols As Variant 'define which columns to select
    ArrCols = Array("C", "E", "F", "H")

    Dim UnifiedRange As Range 'we collect the ranges here

    Dim Col As Variant
    For Each Col In ArrCols
        If UnifiedRange Is Nothing Then 'first range
            Set UnifiedRange = ws.Range(Col & "1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp))
        Else 'all following ranges
            Set UnifiedRange = Union(UnifiedRange, ws.Range(Col & "1", ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp)))
        End If
    Next Col

    'this is just to visualize what the UnifiedRange contains
    UnifiedRange.Select
End Sub
```

[image]

---

#### Alternative: Maximal used range is selected

Advantage of this one is that you can copy/paste while the first selection doesn't allow copy/paste.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SelectMAXUsedRangeOfSeveralColumns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim ArrCols As Variant
    ArrCols = Array("C", "E", "F", "H")

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim UnifiedRange As Range

    Dim Col As Variant
    For Each Col In ArrCols
        LastRow = Application.Max(LastRow, ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, Col).End(xlUp).Row)
        If UnifiedRange Is Nothing Then
            Set UnifiedRange = ws.Columns(Col)
        Else
            Set UnifiedRange = Union(UnifiedRange, ws.Columns(Col))
        End If
    Next Col

    Set UnifiedRange = Intersect(UnifiedRange, ws.Range(ArrCols(0) & "1", ws.Cells(LastRow, ArrCols(UBound(ArrCols)))))

    'this is just to visualize what the UnifiedRange contains
    UnifiedRange.Select
End Sub
```

[image]

---

#### Or even shorter

Might be not as accurate as the long version.

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub SelectMAXUsedRangeOfSeveralColumns()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Dim UnifiedRange As Range
    Set UnifiedRange = Intersect(ws.UsedRange, ws.Range("C:C,E:E,F:F,H:H"))


    'this is just to visualize what the UnifiedRange contains
    UnifiedRange.Select
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You may be able to increase the accuracy of that last one with `.SpecialCells` to only take non-blank cells: `Set UnifiedRange = Intersect(Union(ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas), ws.UsedRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)), ws.Range("C:C,E:E,F:F,H:H"))`?  (Or use `SpecialCells` to trim `UnifiedRange` after it is first defined - might be *slightly* faster?)

Comment: @Chronocidal Yes, I think you can, that would result in the same selection as the first option in my answer (downside: no copy/paste). I think the best option here depends much on what the OP wants to do afterwards. • Nevertheless another shorter version for the first option here, nice.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Union` to combine ranges into one

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim CLastRow As Long, ELastRow As Long, FLastRow As Long, HLastRow As Long

' Update with your Sheet reference
With YourSheet
    CLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    ELastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    FLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    HLastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row

    Set rng = Union(.Range("C1:C" & CLastRow), _
                    .Range("E1:E" & ELastRow), _
                    .Range("F1:F" & FLastRow), _
                    .Range("H1:H" & HLastRow))
End With
```

Personally though, I'd keep them as separate ranges and just do the same operation on each of them if needed.

Comment: Thanks but the number of rows will change for each column. Sometimes it might be 4 rows other times 6,7 etc.

Comment: You just make that dynamic

Answer (score 1):

You can create a multi-area `Range` with the [`Union` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.union), like so:

```
Set Combined_Rage = Union(Range1, Range2) 'You can have up to 30 different Ranges
```

Please note that [`Worksheet.UsedRange`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.usedrange) is something completely different, and is a read-only object set by Excel